# Countdown timer in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, timer

I need a solution for this issue. I want to make a countdown timer where the deadline is taken from database .. Here is my code to take the remaining time

```
exam_model = modelUjian.objects.get(kodeujian=kodeujian)
finish_time = datetime.combine(exam_model.date, exam_model.finishtime)
current_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
time_left = finish_time - current_time 

context = {"time_left":time_left}
return render(request,'mulaiujian.html', context)
```

But i don't know how to show it in HTML. I try some method but it's not working .. nothing appear on countdown span below
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p>Waktu tersisa: <span id="countdown"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript ..

```
<script>
        var countdown = { time_left };  // mengambil countdown dari context di views

        var x = setInterval(function() {
            var hours = Math.floor(countdown / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((countdown % 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = Math.floor(countdown % 60);

            // menampilkan waktu dalam format hh:mm:ss
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (countdown <= 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Waktu telah habis!";
            } else {
                countdown--;
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: @Rojo Nothing appear inside the span countdown

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Rojo There is no error at all .. That's why I'm a bit confused ..

Comment: have you inspected the actual Javascript output? Are you sure it says `var countdown = 1000` (or some other numeric value) rather than something that's not valid syntax? (We don't see how you pass the variables to the template to render.)

Comment: Adding on to Robin, add `console.log(countdown);` after the variable is declared to ensure that the variable is properly created.

Comment: if that's all fine, then try putting a breakpoint inside the function that should be running every second, and stepping through to see what's happening. We can't do that for you as we don't have your HTML.

Comment: context = {"time_left":time_left}
return render(request,'mulaiujian.html', context)

I pass the time_left like this .. I just found an error just now .. it says time_left is not defined ..

Comment: there's your problem then - so the issue is in Python code that you didn't show us...

Comment: @RobinZigmond I just edit it. my python code is just like that .. I get time_left then i pass to html .. I checked the time_left and it's correct ..

Comment: what is `waktu_tersia`? Isn't that supposed to be `time_left`?

Comment: yes it is .. Sorry I forgot to translate it to english .. that supposed to be time_left ...

Comment: oh sorry, you were talking about the Javascript. It's been a while since I used Django, so I didn't spot this straight away - but shouldn't you use `{{ time_left }}` to output the template value? As I said in my first comment, you would have noticed the problem straight away had you checked the actual JS code output. (As it happens, `{ time_left }` is valid JS syntax, but crashes when there's no JS variable in scope called `time_left`, which of course there isn't.)

Comment: I just fixed it! Thanks for your reply here :) Appreciate it